# How to style single-selected <v-list-item> item over multiple sub-groups?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vuetify and Vue in general, and can not seem to figure this one out. I have a need to create multiple sub-groups, from which only **one option** can be selected under the "parent" list.

So for example I have an array of cats:

```
options:["Crookshanks", "Garfield", "Leeroy"]
```

which are split over 2 sub-groups (pseudo code below)

```
subgroup 1
  Crookshanks
  Garfield
subgroup 2
  Leeroy
```

From my end, I've achieved extracting the text content of the selected item which replaces itself if another option is clicked (not pretty, but works).

Now I'd like to create some sort of visual changes (highlight or a check mark) so that it would be clear which item is selected. It should be a toggle-effect on one selected item at a time only, so that if any other option is selected, the effect on the previous option clears. Setting a manual active class unfortunately did not work (I suspect it's not available for sub-groups?):

```
<v-list-item 
active-class="selectedCat">
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/oNjwEBM) is a Codepen for playing around. Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use the component `v-list-item-group` for highlight the selected element. Try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      fictionalSelected = {{ fictionalSelected }}
    </div>
    <div>
      realSelected = {{ realSelected }}
    </div>

    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-card class="ma-1" width="700">
        <v-list>
          <v-list-group prepend-icon="pets">
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-title>CATS</v-list-item-title>
            </template>
            <v-list-group no-action sub-group>
              <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>Fictional</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </template>

              <v-list-item-group v-model="fictionalSelected" @change="fictionalChanged">
                <v-list-item v-for="cat in fictionals">
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ cat }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list-group>

            <v-list-group sub-group no-action>
              <template v-slot:activator>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>Real</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </template>
              <v-list-item-group v-model="realSelected" @change="realChanged">
                <v-list-item v-for="cat in reals">
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ cat }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list-item-group>
            </v-list-group>
          </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
      </v-card>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    fictionals: ['Crookshanks', 'Garfield'],
    fictionalSelected: null,
    reals: ['Leeroy'],
    realSelected: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    fictionalChanged() {
      console.log('fictionalChanged');
      this.realSelected = null;
    },
    realChanged() {
      console.log('realChanged');
      this.fictionalSelected = null;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I tried to implement this here: https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/KKdqeZg. The highlighting works, but only within its own sub-group. My main problem is making 2 sub-groups behave as one sub-group. For example if you select "Crookshanks" from fictionals, and then click on "Leeroy" from reals, Crookshanks would toggle off and get un-selected. That's the pickle I have not yet achieved!

Comment: I change my answer. This is what you want?

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yes, now it works as intended! Thank you ever so much for thinking along, this will be very useful!